# Microsoft SharePoint Guidance: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs, patterns-and-practices

I am using Microsoft SharePoint Guidance for logging and exception handling in my SharePoint timer job,  my solution in SharePoint 2007 worked perfectly (and is working).

Right now I am in the process of upgrading my solution to Visual Studio 2010,  I took new version of SPG for SharePoint 2010 and compiled the assemblies.

However I am getting following exception, seems that Service Location assembly is not being loaded correctly,  I have removed the assembly reference multiple times I am not sure what is going wrong with loading the assembly.

Any Pointers?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          10/25/2012 11:52:00 AM
Event ID:      6398
Task Category: Timer
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      
User:          NETWORK SERVICE
Computer:      
Description:
The Execute method of job definition Halliburton.SharePoint.SiteAudit.SiteAddTimerJob (ID ab997783-7c34-4e5d-bade-30ea57ef1a0c) threw an exception. More information is included below.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your replies,  it seems that some old version of DLLs are being held in the memory.  I run IISRESET command and restarted the Timer Service and the error was gone.

So problem to the solution is the Microsoft Way -- RESET :)

"Sudhir Kesharwani"

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding that DLL to the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) using gacutil or copying it to the BIN folder of the SharePoint web app directory in inetpub...

Comment: My Solution Package does the GAC installation,  I am able to see the assembly installed in the GAC

Comment: Does that DLL have any reference DLLs that are missing?  You can use tools like .NET Reflector to open the DLL and see what it references.